# Difference between a custom AlertDialog and a custom Dialog

Tags: android

I am wondering what is the difference of having a custom Dialog as opposed to a custom AlertDialog is? Is it the fact that they offer free functionality in the form of buttons, lists, checkboxes etc in the dialog?

Secondly, I was wondering if the code fragment for custom AlertDialog available @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html (code reproduced below) is complete. I tried using it and it crashes the moment I call dialog.show():

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(
                             LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create();
```

While code for creating a custom dialog (which works) is much simpler:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom);
dialog.setTitle("Shopping List Name");
dialog.setCancelable(true); 
dialog.show();
```

Thanks for you patience.

M@nish

Edit: I got it to work finally. I think I now understand the difference between Dialog and AlertDialog. I've documented this @ http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/dialog-vs-alertdialog/

Comment: What does your logcat says when the app crashed?

Comment: Unfortunately I've changed my code since and I cannot remember where the exception was exactly. I remember thought that it was a null pointer exception.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349338/what-is-the-difference-between-dialog-and-alertdialog/53349404#:~:text=AlertDialog%20is%20a%20lightweight%20version,do%20even%20more%20complex%20things%20.